# Close window after form is filled

Tags: html

at the bottom is what I currently have on Page A. It opens Page B which is a form. After they submit the form it directs them to the second URL after Source=.

What I am trying to do is make it so it closes the window instead of redirecting to another page.

I have already tried javascript:window.close() and it completely broke the link preventing the first page from even loading.

```
<a href="URL1?Source=URL2">Leave a comment or a question and receive&#160;an answer</a>
```

URL1 = form which opens in a new window
URL2 = page the form redirects to after completion.

If it makes a difference I am working in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Are you able to modify the code behind URL1?

Comment: @IrishGeek82 the page it opens? Unfortunately no I cannot. I would have added something that closed it after submit if I could.

Comment: Try <a href="javascript:close_window();">Close message</a>

Comment: @user1929959 No I get the same error as when I used Javascript:close.Window()

Comment: @Aaron, is URL1 not in the same domain as the page with the link to it?